# Does form_valid() in django saves the ModelForm instance by default?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

The official documentation says that form_valid() is called when valid form data is POSTed. And doesn't say anything about saving data. But I'm reading a book where it says that

> the default behavior of this method is saving the instance (for
>   modelforms ) and redirecting user to success_url
>   .

So, I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 4):

For that you need to see the implementation of [**`post`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L135) method of `ProcessFormView`(which is sub-classed by `CreateView`):

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then check if it's valid.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

You see that `form.is_valid()` method is called and it returns true if the form has been validated. Then you should check how [**`form_valid()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123) method works in `ModelFormMixin`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Its kind of straight forward, data saved to DB using `form.save()` method and then it calls [**`super class's form_valid()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L57) method, in which it redirects to the [**`success url`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L49).

Answer (score 0):

Well I found another documentation on Editing mixins where it does say

> Saves the form instance, sets the current object for the view, and redirects to get_success_url().

So, it does.